# How do I fix a 429 request error for my api project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

I'm trying to build a very simple project off of FreeCodeCamp which uses API information in order to deliver weather information. I'm using the Heroku App in order to be able to use the API while it's still a local host. However, I'm receiving 2 errors, and I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. Any assistance?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", ()=> {
    let long;
    let lat;

    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            long = position.coords.longitude;
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            const proxy=`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`;
            const api=`${proxy}https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&
            exclude={part}&appid={bdd50c9439280eb7362c1f796ce614ae}`;
            
            fetch(api)
            .then(response =>{
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data =>{
                console.log(data);
            })
        });
    }else {
        h1.textContent = "hey dis is not working because not enabled"
    };
    
});
```

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
    height:100vh;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(47,150,163),rgb(48,62,143));
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color:white;

}
.location,.temperature {
    height: 30vh;
    width:50%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.temperature{
    flex-direction: column;
}
.degree-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.degree-section span{
    margin: 10px;
    font-size:30px
}
.degree-section h2{
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="location">
        <h1 class="location-timezone">Timezone</h1>
        <p>Icon</p>
    </div>
    <div class="temperature">
        <div class="degree-section">
        <h2 class="temp-degree">34</h2>
        <span>F</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="temp-description">It's friggin cold</div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rn4D.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

> The HTTP 429 `Too many requests` response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").

You need to check what the actual limit is, and probably avoid doing the call on page load or exceeding its value.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)